# Do I need extra code for Image Field in Django

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I have this in Model

```
image_name = models.ImageField(upload_to='accounts/')
```

In my view I have

```
def account_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = AccountForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = AccountForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('account_form.html', {
            'form': form,
    })
```

Do I need to do extra coding for saving image or django will do it itself

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to pass `request.FILES` to your account form as well.

```
form = AccountForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # A form bound to the POST data
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

> Other than the `save()` and `save_m2m()` methods, a `ModelForm` works exactly the same way as any other forms form. For example, the `is_valid()` method is used to check for validity, the `is_multipart()` method is used to determine whether a form requires multipart file upload (and hence whether `request.FILES` must be passed to the form), etc.

Comment: I tried that , selected the image but i keep getting this error `This field is required.`

Comment: Wow, that took me way to long to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Also make sure your form `enctype` is set in the HTML to submit file data:

```
<form action="..." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: This, in addition to adding `request.FILES` to AccountForm, worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: For a record,  it might be obvious, but if Django creates (generates) your form, `request.Files` isn't required, some details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: In addition to the above link - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs